# Suave "Hello World!" program doesn't work with visual studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, mono, suave

I got runtime errors trying to execute the "Hello World!" program from Suave web page:

open Suave.Web
open Suave.Successful

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    startWebServer defaultConfig (OK "Hello, Suave!")
    0
```

With this errors:

> Loaded assembly: /Users/[myUserName]/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/SuaveRestApi/SuaveRestApi/bin/Debug/SuaveRestApi.exe
>   Loaded assembly: /Users/[myUserName]/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/SuaveRestApi/SuaveRestApi/bin/Debug/FSharp.Core.dll
>   [External] Loaded assembly: /Users/[myUserName]/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/SuaveRestApi/SuaveRestApi/bin/Debug/Suave.dll
>   [External] Loaded assembly:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.0/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   [External] Loaded assembly:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.0/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll
>   [External] Method idx 6984 is greater than number of rows (6984) in
>   PPDB MethodDebugInformation table, for method
>   .$YoLo:.cctor in
>   '/Users/[myUserName]/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/SuaveRestApi/SuaveRestApi/bin/Debug/Suave.pdb'.
>   Likely a malformed PDB file. Stacktrace:
>
> at  <0xffffffff>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init (intptr) [0x00007] in
>   <699ddfd029d348d1a69fb1f9fc28d7cb>:0   at YoLo/UTF8.get_utf8 ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/ademar/Projects/release/suave/src/Suave/Utils/YoLo.fs:447   at
>   Suave.Successful.OK (string) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/ademar/Projects/release/suave/src/Suave/Combinators.fs:136   at
>   App.main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/[myUserName]/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/SuaveRestApi/SuaveRestApi/App.fs:6
>   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_int_object
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00057] in
>   <5c0abea33afd9276a7450383a3be0a5c>:0 Memory around native instruction
>   pointer (0x7fff71ccc23e): 0x7fff71ccc22e  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 48 01
>   00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  .......H...I.... 0x7fff71ccc23e  73 08 48 89 c7
>   e9 6f a1 ff ff c3 55 48 89 e5 41  s.H...o....UH..A 0x7fff71ccc24e  57
>   41 56 41 55 41 54 53 48 81 ec 88 00 00 00 49  WAVAUATSH......I
>   0x7fff71ccc25e  89 f4 48 8d 05 01 c3 cb 32 48 8b 00 48 8d 9d 60 
>   ..H.....2H..H..`
>
> Native stacktrace:
>
> 0   mono                                0x000000010ba29842
>   mono_dump_native_crash_info + 898     1   mono
>   0x000000010b9cd303 mono_handle_native_crash + 195     2
>   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff71d77b3d _sigtramp + 29
>     3   mono                                0x000000010bcdf008
>   simple_lower_case_mapping_higharea_table0 + 20296     4
>   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff71c351c9 abort + 127    5 
>   mono                                0x000000010bbf9c5f
>   mono_log_write_logfile + 351  6   mono
>   0x000000010bc15dac monoeg_g_log + 204     7   mono
>   0x000000010bac9e68 mono_ppdb_get_seq_points + 1112    8   mono
>   0x000000010b93492f mono_method_to_ir + 1151   9   mono
>   0x000000010b91ade7 mini_method_compile + 3479     10  mono
>   0x000000010b91e32c mono_jit_compile_method_inner + 76     11  mono
>   0x000000010b921cc9 mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt + 2665    12  mono
>   0x000000010b925d8e mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 526  13  mono
>   0x000000010bb241d4 do_runtime_invoke + 84     14  mono
>   0x000000010bb201a8 mono_runtime_class_init_full + 872     15  mono
>   0x000000010b97a69c mono_generic_class_init + 28   16  ???
>   0x000000010beb7e2c 0x0 + 4494949932   17  mono
>   0x000000010b9261d3 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1619     18  mono
>   0x000000010bb241d4 do_runtime_invoke + 84     19  mono
>   0x000000010bb27cac do_exec_main_checked + 156     20  mono
>   0x000000010b98d19d mono_jit_exec + 349    21  mono
>   0x000000010b99037f mono_main + 11615  22  mono
>   0x000000010b915078 main + 264     23  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff71b8ced9 start + 1 Pkilling 0x70000ed57000 from 0x1115795c0
>   Pkilling 0x70000eb54000 from 0x1115795c0 Entering thread summarizer
>   pause from 0x1115795c0 Finished thread summarizer pause from
>   0x1115795c0.
>
> Waiting for dumping threads to resume
>
> Debug info from gdb:
>
> (lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.UoI26p' Executing
>   commands in '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.UoI26p'. (lldb) process attach
>   --pid 1457 Process 1457 stopped
>   * thread #1, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
>       frame #0: 0x00007fff71ccb2d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4:
>   ->  0x7fff71ccb2d2 <+10>: jae    0x7fff71ccb2dc            ; <+20>
>       0x7fff71ccb2d4 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
>       0x7fff71ccb2d7 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff71cc6381            ; cerror
>       0x7fff71ccb2dc <+20>: retq    Target 0: (mono) stopped.
>
> Executable module set to
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.0/bin/mono".
>   Architecture set to: x86_64h-apple-macosx. (lldb) thread list Process
>   1457 stopped
>   * thread #1: tid = 0xd6f5, 0x00007fff71ccb2d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, name = 'tid_307', queue =
>   'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP   thread #2: tid
>   = 0xd6f6, 0x00007fff71cc97de libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10, name = 'SGen worker'   thread #3: tid = 0xd6f8, 0x00007fff71cc61b6
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'Finalizer'
>
>   thread #4: tid = 0xd6f9, 0x00007fff71cc93e6
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib`__recvfrom + 10, name = 'Debugger agent'
>   thread #5: tid = 0xd700, 0x00007fff71cc7b6a
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10   thread #6: tid =
>   0xd701, 0x00007fff71cc7b6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn +
>   10 (lldb) thread backtrace all
>   * thread #1, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP   * frame #0: 0x00007fff71ccb2d2
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
>       frame #1: 0x000000010ba299b6 mono`mono_dump_native_crash_info at mini-posix.c:1079 [opt]
>       frame #2: 0x000000010ba29862 mono`mono_dump_native_crash_info(signal="SIGABRT",
>   ctx=0x00007ffee42eb0f0, info=<unavailable>) at mini-posix.c:1102 [opt]
>       frame #3: 0x000000010b9cd303 mono`mono_handle_native_crash(signal="SIGABRT",
>   ctx=0x00007ffee42eb0f0, info=0x00007ffee42eb088) at
>   mini-exceptions.c:3197 [opt]
>       frame #4: 0x00007fff71d77b3d libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 29
>       frame #5: 0x00007fff71ccc23f libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 11
>       frame #6: 0x00007fff71d82c1c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 285
>       frame #7: 0x00007fff71c351c9 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
>       frame #8: 0x000000010bbf9c5f mono`mono_log_write_logfile(log_domain=<unavailable>,
>   level=<unavailable>, hdr=<unavailable>, message="Method idx 6984 is
>   greater than number of rows (6984) in PPDB MethodDebugInformation
>   table, for method <StartupCode$Suave>.$YoLo:.cctor in
>   '/Users/[myUserName]/Library/Mobile
>   Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/SuaveRestApi/SuaveRestApi/bin/Debug/Suave.pdb'.
>   Likely a malformed PDB file.") at mono-log-common.c:135 [opt]
>       frame #9: 0x000000010bc15dac mono`monoeg_g_log [inlined] monoeg_g_logstr(log_domain=0x0000000000000000,
>   log_level=G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, msg=) at goutput.c:117 [opt]
>       frame #10: 0x000000010bc15d83 mono`monoeg_g_log [inlined] monoeg_g_logv_nofree(format=<unavailable>, args=<unavailable>) at
>   goutput.c:128 [opt]
>       frame #11: 0x000000010bc15d70 mono`monoeg_g_log [inlined] monoeg_g_logv(format=, args=) at
>   goutput.c:135 [opt]
>       frame #12: 0x000000010bc15d70 mono`monoeg_g_log(log_domain=0x0000000000000000,
>   log_level=G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, format=<unavailable>) at goutput.c:144
>   [opt]
>       frame #13: 0x000000010bac9e68 mono`mono_ppdb_get_seq_points(minfo=,
>   source_file=, source_file_list=,
>   source_files=, seq_points=0x00007ffee42eb730,
>   n_seq_points=) at debug-mono-ppdb.c:427 [opt]
>       frame #14: 0x000000010b93492f mono`mono_method_to_ir(cfg=<unavailable>, method=<unavailable>,
>   start_bblock=0x0000000000000000, end_bblock=0x0000000000000000,
>   return_var=0x0000000000000000, inline_args=0x0000000000000000,
>   inline_offset=<unavailable>, is_virtual_call=<unavailable>) at
>   method-to-ir.c:6674 [opt]
>       frame #15: 0x000000010b91ade7 mono`mini_method_compile(method=, opts=374434303,
>   domain=0x00007fbc91f02f00, flags=JIT_FLAG_RUN_CCTORS, parts=0,
>   aot_method_index=-1) at mini.c:3455 [opt]
>       frame #16: 0x000000010b91e32c mono`mono_jit_compile_method_inner(method=0x00007fbc94832ea8,
>   target_domain=0x00007fbc91f02f00, opt=<unavailable>,
>   error=0x00007ffee42ebd60) at mini.c:4043 [opt]
>       frame #17: 0x000000010b921cc9 mono`mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt(method=0x00007fbc94832ea8,
>   opt=, jit_only=1, error=0x00007ffee42ebd60) at
>   mini-runtime.c:2411 [opt]
>       frame #18: 0x000000010b925d8e mono`mono_jit_runtime_invoke [inlined] mono_jit_compile_method_jit_only(method=<unavailable>,
>   error=0x00007ffee42ebd60) at mini-runtime.c:2471 [opt]
>       frame #19: 0x000000010b925d6e mono`mono_jit_runtime_invoke(method=, obj=,
>   params=0x0000000000000000, exc=,
>   error=0x00007ffee42ebd60) at mini-runtime.c:3011 [opt]
>       frame #20: 0x000000010bb241d4 mono`do_runtime_invoke(method=0x00007fbc94832ea8,
>   obj=0x0000000000000000, params=0x0000000000000000,
>   exc=0x00007ffee42ebd08, error=0x00007ffee42ebd60) at object.c:2960
>   [opt]
>       frame #21: 0x000000010bb201a8 mono`mono_runtime_class_init_full [inlined] mono_runtime_try_invoke(method=,
>   obj=, params=, error=0x00007ffee42ebd60) at
>   object.c:3069 [opt]
>       frame #22: 0x000000010bb20167 mono`mono_runtime_class_init_full(vtable=0x00007fbc9402ee60,
>   error=0x00007ffee42ebd60) at object.c:526 [opt]
>       frame #23: 0x000000010b97a69c mono`mono_generic_class_init(vtable=) at
>   jit-icalls.c:1511 [opt]
>       frame #24: 0x000000010beb7e2c
>       frame #25: 0x000000010b9261d3 mono`mono_jit_runtime_invoke(method=<unavailable>, obj=<unavailable>,
>   params=0x00007ffee42ec148, exc=0x00007fbc9402ee60,
>   error=<unavailable>) at mini-runtime.c:3148 [opt]
>       frame #26: 0x000000010bb241d4 mono`do_runtime_invoke(method=0x00007fbc91f04798,
>   obj=0x0000000000000000, params=0x00007ffee42ec148,
>   exc=0x0000000000000000, error=0x00007ffee42ec180) at object.c:2960
>   [opt]
>       frame #27: 0x000000010bb27cac mono`do_exec_main_checked [inlined] mono_runtime_invoke_checked(method=<unavailable>, obj=<unavailable>,
>   params=<unavailable>, error=0x00007ffee42ec180) at object.c:3128 [opt]
>       frame #28: 0x000000010bb27c9d mono`do_exec_main_checked(method=0x00007fbc91f04798,
>   args=, error=0x00007ffee42ec180) at object.c:4949 [opt]
>       frame #29: 0x000000010b98d19d mono`mono_jit_exec at driver.g.c:1236 [opt]
>       frame #30: 0x000000010b98d18f mono`mono_jit_exec(domain=, assembly=,
>   argc=1, argv=0x00007ffee42ec550) at driver.g.c:1195 [opt]
>       frame #31: 0x000000010b99037f mono`mono_main [inlined] main_thread_handler at driver.g.c:1313 [opt]
>       frame #32: 0x000000010b990348 mono`mono_main(argc=4, argv=) at driver.g.c:2483 [opt]
>       frame #33: 0x000000010b915078 mono`main [inlined] mono_main_with_options(argc=<unavailable>, argv=<unavailable>) at
>   main.c:50 [opt]
>       frame #34: 0x000000010b915064 mono`main(argc=4, argv=) at main.c:405 [opt]
>       frame #35: 0x00007fff71b8ced9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>       frame #36: 0x00007fff71b8ced9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1   thread #2, name = 'SGen worker'
>       frame #0: 0x00007fff71cc97de libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
>       frame #1: 0x00007fff71d83593 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 724
>       frame #2: 0x000000010bbf10ee mono`thread_func [inlined] mono_os_cond_wait(mutex=<unavailable>) at mono-os-mutex.h:173 [opt]
>       frame #3: 0x000000010bbf10db mono`thread_func at sgen-thread-pool.c:165 [opt]
>       frame #4: 0x000000010bbf10cd mono`thread_func(data=0x0000000000000000) at sgen-thread-pool.c:196
>   [opt]
>       frame #5: 0x00007fff71d80305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
>       frame #6: 0x00007fff71d8326f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
>       frame #7: 0x00007fff71d7f415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13   thread #3, name = 'Finalizer'
>       frame #0: 0x00007fff71cc61b6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
>       frame #1: 0x000000010bb9e9aa mono`finalizer_thread [inlined] mono_os_sem_wait(flags=MONO_SEM_FLAGS_ALERTABLE) at
>   mono-os-semaphore.h:90 [opt]
>       frame #2: 0x000000010bb9e99f mono`finalizer_thread at mono-coop-semaphore.h:43 [opt]
>       frame #3: 0x000000010bb9e985 mono`finalizer_thread(unused=) at gc.c:918 [opt]
>       frame #4: 0x000000010bb49e13 mono`start_wrapper [inlined] start_wrapper_internal at threads.c:1151 [opt]
>       frame #5: 0x000000010bb49d83 mono`start_wrapper(data=0x00007fbc91f34850) at threads.c:1211 [opt]
>       frame #6: 0x00007fff71d80305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
>       frame #7: 0x00007fff71d8326f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
>       frame #8: 0x00007fff71d7f415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13   thread #4, name = 'Debugger agent'
>       frame #0: 0x00007fff71cc93e6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__recvfrom + 10
>       frame #1: 0x000000010ba7e45e mono`socket_transport_recv(buf=2001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, len=11) at
>   debugger-agent.c:1108 [opt]
>       frame #2: 0x000000010ba6f296 mono`debugger_thread [inlined] transport_recv(len=11) at debugger-agent.c:1518 [opt]
>       frame #3: 0x000000010ba6f27c mono`debugger_thread(arg=<unavailable>) at debugger-agent.c:9484 [opt]
>       frame #4: 0x000000010bb49e13 mono`start_wrapper [inlined] start_wrapper_internal at threads.c:1151 [opt]
>       frame #5: 0x000000010bb49d83 mono`start_wrapper(data=0x00007fbc91f389a0) at threads.c:1211 [opt]
>       frame #6: 0x00007fff71d80305 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
>       frame #7: 0x00007fff71d8326f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 70
>       frame #8: 0x00007fff71d7f415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13   thread #5
>       frame #0: 0x00007fff71cc7b6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>       frame #1: 0x00007fff71d7f630 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 446
>       frame #2: 0x00007fff71d7f405 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13   thread #6
>       frame #0: 0x00007fff71cc7b6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>       frame #1: 0x00007fff71d7f630 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 446
>       frame #2: 0x00007fff71d7f405 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13 (lldb) detach
>
> ================================================================= Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.
>
> (lldb) quit Process 1457 detached

Comment: `....Likely a malformed PDB file....` Was this project recompiled or from some archive? I would just try cleaning and recompiling the project from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... The solution compiles fine from scratch but throws those errors when executing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with Visual Studio for Mac and Suave. I did the same test in Visual Studio Code (for mac also) and worked fine.

Comment: please report the VS4Mac bug